# Tor doesn't work until I run "Tor" in the terminal

Tags: configuration, onion-routing, tor-install

Tor@default.service fails to run and journalctl -eu tor@default outputs this - https://campfirebg.eu5.org/upload/log.txt
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Using this command to filter you log file

```
cat log.txt | grep -F '[warn]' | grep -v 'Failed to parse/validate' | grep -P -o '\[warn\] \K.*' | uniq
```

Gives this output:

```
Directory /var/lib/tor cannot be read: Permission denied
Directory /var/lib/tor/keys cannot be read: Permission denied
/var/lib/tor is not owned by this user (debian-tor, 127) but by rado (1000). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user?
Fixing permissions on directory /var/lib/tor
/var/lib/tor/keys is not owned by this user (debian-tor, 127) but by rado (1000). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user?
/home/rado/onion/service is not owned by this user (debian-tor, 127) but by root (0). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user?
```

It looks like the tor service is running under the user `debian-tor`, so you need to change ownership of these directories to `debian-tor`.

Something like this should fix it:

```
sudo chown -R debian-tor /var/lib/tor /home/rado/onion/service
```